# Average multiple columns by FIPS

Tags: r, dplyr

Based on the data below how can I average the columns `InIndividuals`, `OutIndividuals`, `InAGI` and `OutAGI` by `FIPS`? I am using `FIPS` because there are several counties with the same name. So the column `Key` is no longer needed as it's a concatenate of `FIPS` and `Year`.

Desired output schema/columns:

```
       FIPS   County           State          AvgInIndividuals  AvgOutIndividuals AvgNetMigration AvgInAGI  AvgOutAGI
    1  8001   Adams County    CO             36.0              40.0              -4              388.5     351.0
    2 12001 Alachua County    FL            407.0             404.0               3              277.5     346.5
    3 16001     Ada County    ID             18.5              18.5               0              499.5     462.0
```

Sample data:

```
df = structure(list(FIPS = c(12001L, 8001L, 16001L, 12001L, 
    8001L, 16001L), State = c("FL", "CO", "ID", "FL", 
    "CO", "ID"), County = c("Alachua County", "Adams County", 
    "Ada County", "Alachua County", "Adams County", "Ada County"), 
        InIndividuals = c(433L, 30L, 16L, 381L, 42L, 21L), OutIndividuals = c(426L, 33L, 12L, 382L, 47L, 25L), InAGI = c(111L, 222L, 333L, 444L, 555L, 666L), NetMigration = c(7L, -3L, 4L, -1L, -5L, -4L), OutAGI = c(570L, 246L, 135L, 123L, 456L, 789L), FiscalYear = c("2011 - 2012", 
        "2011 - 2012", "2011 - 2012", "2011 - 2012", "2010 - 2011", 
        "2010 - 2011"), Year = c(2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2011L, 2011L, 
        2011L), Key = c(120012012L, 80012012L, 160012012L, 120012011L, 
        80012011L, 160012011L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(Key, County = Origin_Place, 
      FIPS = Origin_FIPS, State = Origin_StateName) %>% 
   summarise(across(matches('(Individuals|AGI)$'), mean, 
    na.rm = TRUE, .names = "Avg{.col}"), .groups = "drop")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 8
        Key County          FIPS State AvgInIndividuals AvgOutIndividuals AvgInAGI AvgOutAGI
      <int> <chr>          <int> <chr>            <dbl>             <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1  80012011 Adams County    8001 CO                  42                47      555       456
2  80012012 Adams County    8001 CO                  30                33      222       246
3 120012011 Alachua County 12001 FL                 381               382      444       123
4 120012012 Alachua County 12001 FL                 433               426      111       570
5 160012011 Ada County     16001 ID                  21                25      666       789
6 160012012 Ada County     16001 ID                  16                12      333       135
```

Comment: Sir, it's combining `InIndividuals` and `OutIndividuals` into one `IndividualsAvg`, whereas I would like separate averages for `In` and `Out` `Individuals` and `AGI`. Plus the output `df1` is missing  `County`, `FIPS` and `State`.

Comment: In my final dataset I will also have a column `NetMigration`, in that case can I just add `NetMigration` to `matches` like `(Individuals|AGI|NetMigration)$' ?

Comment: @Ed_Gravy what is `NetMigration` in the dput dataset.   If you need as a grouping columns, it can be added in the group_by, or else you can use `summarise(NetMigration, across(matches(....` if you don't want mean of `NetMigration` or otherwise you can use `summarise(across(c(NetMigration, matches('(Individuals|AGI)$'), mean,...` assuming NetMigration is the full column name

Comment: sir, It's basically `NetMigration` = `InIdividuals` - `OutIndividuals`. So, the final dataset will have an additional column `AvgNetMigration`. I will do a quick calculation and add it to the sample data.

Comment: @Ed_Gravy then, `summarise(NetMigration = IndIndivudlas - Outindivdiuals, across(...`

Comment: Sorry sir, I just realized I made a mistake instead of `Key` I should be averaging by `FIPS` since each county has a unique `FIPS` to distinguish them even if they have same name.

Comment: So the column `Key` is no longer needed as it's a concatenate of `FIPS` and `Year`, since, basically the average is being calculated for the whole time series by county.

Comment: Sir I tried, `In_Out_Flow_avg = df %>% group_by(FIPS, County, State) %>% summarise(NetMigration = Inflow - Outflow,  across(matches('(Individuals|AGI)$'), mean, na.rm = TRUE, .names = "Avg{.col}"), .groups = "drop")` but the output is not as expected.

Comment: What is your expected

Comment: Good day sir, please see updated post with, thank you.

Comment: @Ed_Gravy try `df %>% 
   group_by(Key, County, 
      FIPS, State ) %>% 
   summarise(AvgNetMigration = mean(NetMigration), across(matches('(Individuals|AGI)$'), mean, 
    na.rm = TRUE, .names = "Avg{.col}"), .groups = "drop")`

Comment: Thank you sir, a slight modification (i.e. removing `Key`) to your code in the comment does the trick. `df %>% group_by(County,FIPS, State ) %>% summarise(AvgNetMigration = mean(NetMigration), across(matches('(Individuals|AGI)$'), mean, na.rm = TRUE, .names = "Avg{.col}"), .groups = "drop")`

Answer (score 2):

```r
aggregate(cbind(InIndividuals, OutIndividuals, InAGI, OutAGI) ~ Key + Origin_Place + Origin_StateName + Origin_FIPS, 
          data = df, 
          mean) |> 
  `colnames<-`(c('Key', 'County', 'State', 'FIPS', 'AvgOutIndividuals', 'AvgInIndividuals', 'AvgInAGI', 'AvgOutAGI'))
```